# usually crash at [ZXCapture dealloc]

Tags: ios, crash, zxing

I am using zxcapture. My program often crashes at a specific point pointed in the following code.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    if (_lastScannedImage) {
        CGImageRelease(_lastScannedImage); // crash here
    }

    if (_session && _session.inputs) {
        for (AVCaptureInput *input in _session.inputs) {
            [_session removeInput:input];
        }
    }

    if (_session && _session.outputs) {
        for (AVCaptureOutput *output in _session.outputs) {
            [_session removeOutput:output];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Yep, error is like  EXC_BAD_ACESS in dealloc

Comment: I found the answer @ https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC/issues/26 let me try it and then i will reply either problem solved or not. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
[self.capture.layer removeFromSuperlayer];
[self.capture stop];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

solved the issue.

Comment: Capture layer should be removed from view. Also Capture session should be stopped before dismiss.